# Pentaho Report Designer Inline css/html styling when report output is HTML

Tags: email, pentaho, inline-styles, report-designer, xaction

Hi pentaho has an example in its sample reports `email_inventory_inline_HTML.xaction` and `inventory.prpt` in the directory: `biserver-ce\pentaho-solutions\bi-developers\reporting\unified-file-format`. The xaction script sends a report defined in `inventory.prpt` by email ( within the body of the email ).

How do I do a similar thing. I am able to send my email via xaction but the resulting report in the email body has not styling or coloring.  How do I implement inline styling in pentaho report designer. I am looking at `invertory.prpt` but cannot figure out how they did this. Help I need styling in my emailed reports.

When I run the example report (`inventory.prpt`) as an html output I realise the elements have in-line css and this is clearly what makes the styling visible in an email body; however my report references css classes for the styling. How do I turn this feature off. I am trying to find what about inventory.prpt makes its html output have inline css but to no avail. Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not really a solution but it worked for me.

I modified the `inventory.prpt` example report to my specifications. I am not sure if this is the case but it seems the css inline feature is custom to the inventory.prpt report canvas. So a few changes and replacements here and there and I was good to go. Like magic !